# Provisioning features specific to Google Earth Pro in the Google Earth API

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am a definite novice with the GE API, and I have a little bit of KML experience, so I apologize if this is a day-one question.

I am considering developing a web-based application using the GE API, and I'm wondering if it's possible to add any of the Google Earth Pro functionality that I have through my Pro license. Specifically, the most recent version of GE Pro contains a Viewshed tool, and I'm wondering if it's at all possible to use the API to programmatically call this feature in the web-based GE instance, or if that feature is something that's restricted to the downloadable client version of GE Pro. Thanks for any help.

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. The Google Earth Api and the Desktop application are totally separate things.

You would have to create your own functionality using the API.

Comment: I was pretty sure this was the case, but I figured I'd ask the experts. Thanks for the response. Now I just need to figure out how to create viewshed polygons with the API (JS and/or KML I'd imagine...).